# Mapstruct together with other annotation-processors in maven-pom

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml, mapstruct, annotation-processor

http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    4.0.0

```
<artifactId>yyy-data</artifactId>
<name>VS yyy (data)</name>

<parent>
    <groupId>de.xxx</groupId>
    <artifactId>yyy-server</artifactId>
    <version>8.1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>
<properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    <distribution.outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/dist</distribution.outputDirectory>
</properties>

<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.mysema.querydsl</groupId>
        <artifactId>querydsl-apt</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.mysema.querydsl</groupId>
        <artifactId>querydsl-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.8</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.8-b01</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.8-b01</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
        <artifactId>mapstruct</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <annotationProcessorPaths>
                    <path>
                        <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
                        <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
                        <version>1.3.0.Final</version>
                    </path>
                </annotationProcessorPaths>
                <annotationProcessors>
                    <annotationProcessor>de.zzz.annotation.processor.GenerateHibernateTypeForEnumProcessor</annotationProcessor>
                    <annotationProcessor>de.zzz.annotation.processor.GenerateHibernateTypeForWertelistenProcessor</annotationProcessor>
                    <annotationProcessor>de.zzz.annotation.processor.BusinessObjectAnnotationProcessor</annotationProcessor>
                    <annotationProcessor>com.mysema.query.apt.jpa.JPAAnnotationProcessor</annotationProcessor>
                </annotationProcessors>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>compile</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>m2e</id>
        <activation>
            <property>
                <name>m2e.version</name>
            </property>
        </activation>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin> 
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>compile</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

Dear all,

I need some help in implementing `mapstruct` in my `project`. I already have some annotation processors which need to be named in the `pom.xml` of maven.
`Mapstruct` recommends to add `annotationProcessorPaths` in the pom.xml. It seems that it is not possible to use both annotations (`annotationProcessorPaths` and `annotationProcessor`) in the same pom. If I do, I get the error

> Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.0:compile (default) on project yyy-data: Compilation failure 
>    [ERROR] Annotation processor 'de.zzz.annotation.processor.GenerateHibernateTypeForEnumProcessor' not found

I did shorten the pom. So there may be more dependencies than really needed.

Thanks in advance
Oliver

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can still use `annotationProcessor`. You would need to add the `mapstruct-processor` in your dependencies and then add `org.mapstruct.ap.MappingProcessor` in the `annotationProcessor`.

The reason why you are seeing the error is because when you define `annotationProcessorPaths` the `maven-compiler-plugin` will only use those for looking for annotation processors and not your other dependencies.

Alternatively you can also add all the annotation processors you have in the `annotationProcessoPaths` instead if your dependencies.

Comment: Thank you very much. Your first proposal solved the issue. 

I have a question to the second. Most of the other annotation processors are self-written and inside the project. I was not able to find out how to set up an annotationProcessorPath for such classes. Could you also give me a hint here?
It should be something like "add the project classpath to the processor paths".

Comment: Well usually you write the annotation processors in a different module and use that module in the annotationProcessorPaths. I don't know whether you can achieve what you are doing from the same module

Comment: @Oliver  Can you help me on the below link.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74918334/mapstruct-not-working-along-with-annotation-processor  I can know where I am making wrong in my pom.xml file