# mapstruct not working along with annotation processor

Tags: spring-boot, mapstruct, parent-pom

I try to combine my custom annotation processor along with mapstruct, it fails. Below is my pom.xml where I am trying to use combine my own custom annotation processor [FieldProperty] with mapstruct, the mapstruct is not generating implementation code. But when I use only mapstruct by removing custom annotation processor then the code is getting generated.

Question:
How to combine custom annotation processor with mapstrct?

```
<!-- Not sure how to combine mapstruct and custom annotation processor -->
            <!-- Here the mapstruct not generating the code, when ever I add the custom annotation -->
    

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.2</version>
        <!-- If required upgrade the spring boot version here -->
        <relativePath />
        <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.mt.mtamp</groupId>
    <artifactId>mt-amp-base-project</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <name>mt-amp-base-project</name>
    <description>Base pom project for all the MT-AMP spring boot projects
    </description>
    <scm>
        <developerConnection>scm:git:origin</developerConnection>
        <url>${CI_PROJECT_URL}</url>
    </scm>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>2021.0.3</spring-cloud.version>
        <org.openapitools.jackson-databind-nullable.version>0.2.2
        </org.openapitools.jackson-databind-nullable.version>
        <org.springdoc.springdoc-openapi-ui.version>1.6.8
        </org.springdoc.springdoc-openapi-ui.version>
        <org.mapstruct.version>1.5.2.Final</org.mapstruct.version>
        <version.mapstruct-lombok>0.2.0</version.mapstruct-lombok>
        <org.maven.surefire.version>2.22.2</org.maven.surefire.version>
        <jacoco.version>0.8.7</jacoco.version>
        <!-- Docker Image name : Image Name and version used in JIB(Docker Image 
            Creation) and JKUBE (Image Name for Helm chart) -->
        <docker.image.name>${CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE}:latest</docker.image.name>
        <!-- Used in Helm chart deploy, needed for DB Service reference -->
        <chart.releasename>${CI_PROJECT_NAME}</chart.releasename>
        <!-- Deployment.yml template for imagePullSecrets from the Gitlab template 
            project -->
        <jkube.resourceDir>.devops/ci/jkube</jkube.resourceDir>
        <!-- Image to be included in HELM chart -->
        <jkube.generator.name>${docker.image.name}</jkube.generator.name>
        <!-- Helm chart outputDir -->
        <jkube.helm.outputDir>.devops/ci/charts/${CI_PROJECT_NAME}
        </jkube.helm.outputDir>
        <jkube.replicas>1</jkube.replicas>
        <helm.source>${project.parent.scm.url}</helm.source>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
            <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-ui</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.8</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openapitools</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind-nullable</artifactId>
            <version>${org.openapitools.jackson-databind-nullable.version}
            </version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Consul service discovery -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-consul-discovery</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- lombok dependency -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
            <artifactId>mapstruct</artifactId>
            <version>${org.mapstruct.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
            <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
            <version>${org.mapstruct.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Junit 5 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mt.mtamp</groupId>
            <artifactId>mtamp-exception-handling</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mt.mtamp</groupId>
            <artifactId>mtamp-custom-annotation</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mt.mtamp</groupId>
            <artifactId>entity-annotation-processing</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok-mapstruct-binding</artifactId>
            <version>${version.mapstruct-lombok}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <!-- version management -->
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
    <!-- Build configuration -->
    <build>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.openapitools</groupId>
                    <artifactId>openapi-generator-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>6.0.0</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>generate</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <inputSpec>
                                    ${openapi.input.spec}
                                </inputSpec>
                                <templateDirectory>${openapi.input.name.template}
                                </templateDirectory>
                                <generatorName>${openapi.input.name}</generatorName>
                                <apiPackage>${openapi.input.api.package}</apiPackage>
                                <modelPackage>${openapi.input.model.package}</modelPackage>
                                <configOptions>
                                    <useTags>true</useTags>
                                    <serializableModel>true</serializableModel>
                                    <ignoreUnknownJacksonAnnotation>true
                                    </ignoreUnknownJacksonAnnotation>
                                    <interfaceOnly>true</interfaceOnly>
                                    <skipDefaultInterface>true</skipDefaultInterface>
                                </configOptions>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>

                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <configuration>
                        <annotationProcessors>
                            <annotationProcessor>com.mt.mtamp.annotation.processor.FieldProcessor
                            </annotationProcessor>
                            <annotationProcessor>org.mapstruct.ap.MappingProcessor</annotationProcessor>
                        </annotationProcessors>
                        <annotationProcessorPaths>
                            <path>
                                <groupId>com.mt.mtamp</groupId>
                                <artifactId>entity-annotation-processing</artifactId>
                                <version>1.0</version>
                            </path>
                            <path>
                                <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
                                <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
                                <version>${org.mapstruct.version}</version>
                            </path>
                            <path>
                                <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                                <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                                <version>${lombok.version}</version>
                            </path>
                            <path>
                                <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                                <artifactId>lombok-mapstruct-binding</artifactId>
                                <version>${version.mapstruct-lombok}</version>
                            </path>
                        </annotationProcessorPaths>
                        <compilerArgs>
                            <compilerArg>-Amapstruct.verbose=true</compilerArg>
                            <compilerArg>
                                -Amapstruct.defaultComponentModel=spring</compilerArg>
                            <compilerArg>-AentityGenerator=${entityGenerator}</compilerArg>
                        </compilerArgs>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>com.google.cloud.tools</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jib-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.1.2</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <from>
                            <image>openjdk:17.0.2-jdk</image>
                        </from>
                        <to>
                            <image>${docker.image.name}</image>
                        </to>
                        <container>
                            <creationTime>USE_CURRENT_TIMESTAMP</creationTime>
                        </container>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <configuration>
                        <excludes>
                            <exclude>
                                <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                                <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                            </exclude>
                        </excludes>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
        <!-- display active profile in compile phase -->
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-help-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>show-profiles</id>
                        <phase>compile</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>active-profiles</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <delimiters>
                        <delimiter>@</delimiter>
                    </delimiters>
                    <useDefaultDelimiters>false</useDefaultDelimiters>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>profile-k8s</id>
            <properties>
                <packaging.type>jar</packaging.type>
            </properties>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>profile-tomcat</id>
            <properties>
                <packaging.type>war</packaging.type>
            </properties>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
                    <exclusions>
                        <exclusion>
                            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
                        </exclusion>
                    </exclusions>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
                    <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
                    <version>4.0.1</version>
                    <scope>provided</scope>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.mt.mtamp</groupId>
                    <artifactId>mtamp-consul-registration</artifactId>
                    <version>1.0</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <configuration>
                            <excludeGroupIds>org.apache.tomcat.embed</excludeGroupIds>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>

        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>profile-jetty</id>
            <properties>
                <packaging.type>war</packaging.type>
            </properties>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
                    <exclusions>
                        <exclusion>
                            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
                        </exclusion>
                    </exclusions>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jetty</artifactId>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.mt.mtamp</groupId>
                    <artifactId>mtamp-consul-registeration</artifactId>
                    <version>1.0</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <configuration>
                            <excludeGroupIds>org.apache.tomcat.embed</excludeGroupIds>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>profile-sql</id>
            <properties>
                <spring.profile.from.maven>postgres</spring.profile.from.maven>
            </properties>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
                    <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.mt.mtamp</groupId>
                    <artifactId>mtamp-sql-repository-starter</artifactId>
                    <version>1.0</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>profile-nosql</id>
            <properties>
                <spring.profile.from.maven>mongodb</spring.profile.from.maven>
            </properties>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.mt.mtamp</groupId>
                    <artifactId>mtamp-nosql-repository-starter</artifactId>
                    <version>1.0</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
</project>
```

I am getting the below exception when I try to combine the both.

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.10.1:compile (default-compile) on project sql-nosql-service: Compilation failure
[ERROR] /C:/Users/senthiln-1/MT-AMP/sql-nosql-sample-application/src/main/java/com/mt/mtamp/employees/mapper/EmployeeMapper.java:[21,8] No implementation was created for EmployeeMapper due to having a problem in the erroneous element java.util.ArrayList. Hint: this often means that some other annotation processor was supposed to process the erroneous element. You can also enable MapStruct verbose mode by setting -Amapstruct.verbose=true as a compilation argument.
```

Comment: I've seen this error when Lombok is there, but it isn't being used anywhere. Are you sure that you have the latest versions of the Lombok MapStruct binding and / or that you even need Lombok